# Django-webpush: Service worker is not supported in your browser (Firefox)

Tags: django, firefox, service-worker

I am using [Django-Webpush](https://github.com/safwanrahman/django-webpush) to push notification on a non-secure connection (I am running it in a local network). I followed the instructions and its working perfectly on Chrome, but in Firefox (version 84.0 - which supports service workers) I get the message that the **service worker is not supported in your browser!**.

I checked other websites that have service workers and they seem to be working fine. I ran the browser with all add-ons deactivated, but the problem still persists.

I also ran the browser with all add-ons disabled to see if anything was preventing it, without any success.

In order to get the message that service workers are not supported in my browser, the following condition should fail in webpush.js :

```
if('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    var serviceWorker = document.querySelector('meta[name="service-worker-js"]').content;
    navigator.serviceWorker.register(serviceWorker).then(function(reg){subBtn.textContent = 'Loading...';
    registration = reg;
    initialiseState(reg);
   });
} else {
   messageBox.textContent = 'Service Worker is not supported in your Browser!';
   messageBox.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Any idea on what else to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently because of the little detail that the webapp is running on http and not https, it required to make the following changes to my Firefox about:config :

switch from false to true:

- alerts.useSystemBackend
- devtools.serviceWorkers.testing.enabled

Unfortunately it doesnt keep the notification in the Windows 10 notification area for more than a few seconds (~ 5 seconds).

I still need it to remain there until the user clicks on it.

EDIT:
*[This is for anyone who is stuck on the same stage of resolving the problem of push notifications not sticking at the Action Center]*
This problem is actually a bug that exists in Firefox for years. They have hardcoded the TTL to 4 seconds and have yet to provide a way for the user to change this in any way or form.

I consider the issue resolved and probably will have to work on Chrome from now and on.